# VS Code resx file extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, resx

Seems like there is no way to automatically create and manage resx files in VS Code now. Does someone know extension for it?

*P.S. Yeah, I know that I can edit resx file as bare xml, but it`s not a right way.*

Answer (score 6):

The problem with resx is that it uses a Visual Studio "Custom Tool" to generate the code for the resources, and so requires Visual Studio to function fully.

I've been working on a replacement to resx that should also work from VS Code. It uses json rather than xml to define the resources, but otherwise behaves much like a resx file. The json resources file uses a ".resj" extension, and has a very simple structure. It currently only supports string resources that can be defined either inline in the json, or in an external file reference.

The project is open source on GitHub here:
https://github.com/MarkPflug/Elemental.JsonResource/

This is available as a nuget package "Elemental.JsonResource", currently only pre-release. Simply add this package to your project to enable using resj files. It doesn't add a runtime dependency to your project, everything is done at build-time. My hope is to provide feature-parity with what a resx file can do, but it could be useful even in its current state.